# Spring MVC either sending JSON or Redirecting to another page

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Hello I have been using Spring 3 for my project, I have been stuck in on point.

```
if(ajax){

        User user = userTemplate.getUser(form.getCreator_id());
        int isPremium = user.getPremium();
        if ( isPremium == 1 ){
            Map<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            resultMap.put("result", "success");
            return new Gson().toJson(resultMap);
        }else{
            return "redirect:/f/redirectedUrl?url="+form.getWeb_page();
        }
    }
```

redirectedUrl controller is just for redirecting, but if the request is ajax request then i want to response the request as json.

How can I achieve this, thanks.

Edit : I can understand if request is ajax or not. My problem is if it is ajax i want to response json, if it is not then i want to redirect.

Comment: Many javascript frameworks inject "X-Requested-With" header. 
Refer to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042865/what-is-the-common-http-header-for-request-by-js-libs/7067675

Comment: I can understand if it is ajax or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your controller to identify if request is ajax or not and based on that you can add your logic.

```
boolean ajax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(
                      getRequest().getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
```

You can decide it from **header("X-Requested-With")** of your httpRequest object.

Comment: No i can understand if the request is from ajax. Yea i already used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ModelAndView getDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRespone response) {


       if(ajax) {
        try {

new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter().write(object, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new ServletServerHttpResponse(response));
        } catch(Exception e) {
              logger.error("Error when converting to json");
        }

        return null;
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("viewName");
    }  
}
```